# NSPredicate to return ANY on self

Tags: core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Is there a method (`NSPredicate` or other function) that returns ANY single existing `NSManagedObject`. Could also be the count of an entity type. No further requirements other than mere existence on self.

```
NSPredicate *fetch = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: "@ANY"]

....
[fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
[fetch setPredicate: predicate];
[fetch setFetchLimit:1];
```

Note that this is the 'root' object, thus no instance at this boot stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but to get a one (arbitrary) object
of your entity just don't add a predicate to the fetch request and set the fetch limit to 
one:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"YourEntity"];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (result == nil) {
    // Error executing fetch request
} else if ([result count] == 0) {
    // Found none
} else {
    // Found one
    NSManagedObject *obj = result[0];
}
```

Comment: thats it. cheers. always used an nsarraycontroller or nsobjectcontroller for that simple purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I'm coming across this a few years later & thought it might be helpful to see this in Swift.  In my testing, this returns the first entry in the data store, not necessarily a random entry from the whole store or even a different one each time.

Assuming that by "ANY" you're OK simply returning the first entry, here's how to do it in Swift.

**for Swift 4.2:**

```
let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<yourEntityName> = yourEntityName.fetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    do {
        let fetchResults = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if fetchResults.count == 0 {
            // found none
        } else {
            // found one
            var obj: NSManagedObject = fetchResults[0]
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
```